# Reference Request - Introductory book on Mathematical Modelling in Economics and Business

Tags: reference-request, finance, economics

I have to take a compulsory course named *Mathematical Modelling in Economics and Business* this semester and have absolutely no background on the subject. I also noticed there is no post on this site recommending *introductory* level texts on the field.

I am not equipped to summarrise the content of the syllabus but if you could you can check it out [here](http://science.cmb.ac.lk/departments/mathematics/undergraduate-programs/special-degrees-mathematics/syllabus-special-degree/#AM3004).

> So can someone please recommend some reading material for a
>   mathematics student for a first look at mathematical finance,
>   economics and the like.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are populars book on Finance and Economics that many undergrads use. I used them as well when I was an undergraduate but different editions.

1. [Essentials of Corporate Finance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0078034752) (Beginners Finance)
2. [Fundamentals of Corporate Finance Alt Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0077479459) (Intermediate Fin)
3. [Principles of Macro Econ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0077318501)
4. [Principles of Micro Econ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/128516590X)

The books above teach the basics on finance and econ which would be the necessary background to understand mathematical modeling in econ and finance.

1. [Microeconomic Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195073401)
2. [A Course in Microeconomic Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691042640)

This two are at the graduate level. The second book takes a more game theoretic approach.

---

Below are books a buddy of mine used in his graduate work on Financial Engineering

**Will update more when my friend sends me the list he used when he gets home.**

1. [Finacial Engineering and Computation: Principles, Mathematics, Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052178171X)
2. [Analysis of Financial Time Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470414359)
3. [Stochastic Calculus for Finance 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387249680) and [Stochastic Calculus for Finance 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192311X)

---

Other resources.

1. [Schwaum's Outline of Intro Mathematical Econ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071762515) looks really basic though not sure if it would be worth it
2. [Mathematics for Econ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393957330) pretty popular older book ('94)
3. [Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691010188)

---

### Quantnet's Best-selling books 2014:

Every year Quantnet puts out a list of the best selling books related to quantitative finance and wall street. You will find that the books I copied over below are ones that potentially relate to your course. However, you can view the full list at [Quantnet's Best-selling Quant Books 2014](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/quantnet-best-selling-quant-books-of-2014.19160/). Also, two of the books by Shreve from my friends list Stochastic Cal 1 and 2 were listed here as well but left out to avoid duplication.

1. [A Primer for the Mathematics of Financial Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979757622)
2. [Fifty Challenginer Problems in Probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486653552)
3. [Cracking the Coding Interview: 150 Programming Questions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/098478280X)
4. [A Linear Algebra Primer for Financial Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979757657)
5. [Financial Options: from Theory to Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/155623872X)

---

I imagine all three lists are a bit of an overkill but this way you can decided which texts may be suitable for your current level. Additionally, from the Quantnet link, there are books on traders experiences if this is the field you want to go into as well as links to previous year's book lists.

Comment: Dustin, really appreciate the effort to put this list together. Almost seems inappropriate to ask for more. But I am still having trouble finding a Microeconomics book I like. Do you have anymore in mind on basic price theory? Say, something concise, mathematical (but not axiomatic) and with exercises that make use of everything from Optimisation to Differential Equations?